# Import a function from another notebook changing a parameter

Tags: import, replacement

I am trying to import a function obtained from another notebook into my current notebook. In addition to importing it, I must replace all x with (x + 40).

Here goes na example:

Notebook 1:

```
b=2;
N[x_]=x^2+b;
```

The following should appear on Notebook 2:

```
N[x_]=(x+40)^2+2;
```

Could anyone help me with this?

Comment: myself, would just use the mouse and copy and paste the code into the new notebook and change the definition there. Also, you should really use `:=` for function definition in this case. But the way I do things for larger code is put all functions definitions in one notebook, and put the code which uses them in separate notebook. This way, I just need to evaluate the definitions notebook once at start to use them from any where.

Comment: If you're trying to reuse functions, write a package. It's a small amount of initial stuff you have to learn but it makes your life _much_ better

Comment: @b3m2a1 a package is of course ultimately the right way, but for beginners and for small tasks it is overkill I think. I found using one notebook for definitions and one notebook as the "working" notebook which uses the functions there a good practical way until one graduates to a package.

Comment: The function is too big to just copy and paste, I think I'll try to write a package. Is there any place that can teach me how to do so? And how can I replace the variable x for (x+40) in this package?

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/89293)